# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, .net, chatbot

When I am trying to run my application I am getting this exception

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

In `Global.asaxcs` file in `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` line

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Bot_Application2_test
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: add check for null before this line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. 
In Solution Explorer -> Web.config . Make sure AppID & AppSecret is not null.
{

```
 <appSettings>
    <!-- update these with your appid and one of your appsecret keys-->
    <add key="AppId" value="YourAppId" />
    <add key="AppSecret" value="YourAppSecret" />
  </appSettings>
```

}

Hope it helps you!

Comment: how could I get to know AppId and AppSecret values?